# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'view_profile_with_pk' with keyword arguments

Tags: python, django

this error is killing me please help I sat on in like for 3 hours and I couldn't even know why is the error happening I will give all the information needed, btw I am new to Django so please explain if you can Thank You,
Error:  NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'view_profile_with_pk' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account\/profile\/\(P(?P[^/]+)\\d\+\)\/$']
My URLs .py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import (PasswordResetView , PasswordResetDoneView, PasswordResetConfirmView,
PasswordResetCompleteView)
app_name= 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.register, name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('profile/', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    path('profile/(P<pk>\d+)/', views.view_profile, name='view_profile_with_pk'),
    path('profile/edit/', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    path('change-password/', views.change_password, name='change_password'),

    path('password_reset/', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/',PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),


]
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.urls import reverse
from accounts.forms import (
    RegistrationForm,
    EditProfileForm,
    UserProfileForm
)

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:home')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)

def view_profile(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
        user = request.user
    args = {'user': user}
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', args)

def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        imgF = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            imgF.save()
            return redirect('accounts:view_profile')
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        imgF = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    args = {'form': form , 'img':imgF}
    return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)

def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return redirect('accounts:view_profile')
        else:
            return redirect('accounts:change_password')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/change_password.html', args)
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('home:home')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/login.html',{'error':'username or password is incorrect.','user':user})
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

def logout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auth.logout(request)
        return redirect('home:home')
```

TraceBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\Desktop\Alone-Osama\home\views.py", line 26, in get
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'view_profile_with_pk' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account\\/profile\\/\\(P(?P<pk>[^/]+)\\\\d\\+\\)\\/$']
```

profile.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block head %}
<title>Profile</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Profile</h1>
    <p>Username: {{ user }}</p>
    <p>First name: {{ user.first_name }}</p>
    <p>Last name: {{ user.last_name }}</p>
    <p>Email: {{ user.email }}</p>
    <p>Description: {{ user.userprofile.description }}</p>
    <p>Phone: {{ user.userprofile.phone }}</p>
    <p>City: {{ user.userprofile.city }}</p>
    <p>Website: {{ user.userprofile.website }}</p>
    {% if user.userprofile.image %}
    <img src="{{ user.userprofile.image.url }}" width="240">
    {% endif %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  {% load static %}
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">


  <title>Osama Daghestani</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'navstyle.css' %}">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="{% static 'open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="{% static 'fontawesome/css/all.css'%}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="static/Favicon//apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="static/Favicon//apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="static/Favicon//apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="static/Favicon//apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="static/Favicon//apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="static/Favicon//apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="static/Favicon//apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="static/Favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="static/Favicon//android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="static/Favicon//favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="static/Favicon//favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="static/Favicon//favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="static/Favicon//ms-icon-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home:home' %}">
      <img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" height=30 width=30 class="d-inline-block alighn-top" />
      Osama Daghestani
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="">Post <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span></a>
          <div class="nav-item nav-link dropdown">
  <a  id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    dasdas<img class="UserImage" src="{{ user.userprofile.image.url }}" height="30" width="30"  alt="">
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile' %}"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:edit_profile' %}"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Settings</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:{document.getElementById('logout').submit()}"onclick=""><i class="fas fa-user-minus"></i> Logout</a>
  </div>
</div>



          <form id="logout" method="POST" action="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" />
          </form>
          {% else %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}">Sign Up <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Login <i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>



    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="container">

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

  </div>

  <footer class="text-muted">

    <div class="container text-center">
      <p>©Alone {% now "Y" %} By Osama Daghestani</p>
      </div>

  </footer>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
  ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.post }}
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <h2>{{ text }}</h2>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <h1>{{ post.post }}</h1>
            <p>Posted by {{ post.user.get_full_name }} on {{ post.created }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Other People</h2>
        {% for user in users %}
            <a href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}">
                <h3>{{ user.username }}</h3>
            </a>
            {% if not user in friends %}
            <a href="{% url 'home:change_friends' operation='add' pk=user.pk %}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Friend</button>
            </a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <h2>Friends</h2>
        {% for friend in friends %}
            <a href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile_with_pk' pk=friend.pk %}">
                <h3>{{ friend.username }}</h3>
            </a>
            <a href="{% url 'home:change_friends' operation='remove' pk=friend.pk %}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Remove Friend</button>
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Friend(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @classmethod
    def make_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        friend.users.add(new_friend)

    @classmethod
    def lose_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        friend.users.remove(new_friend)
```

Home Views:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from home.forms import HomeForm
from home.models import Post, Friend


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def get(self, request):

        form = HomeForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.users.id)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.users)
            friends = friend.users.all()
        else:
            friend=1
            friends=(1,)
        args = {
            'form': form, 'posts': posts, 'users': users, 'friends': friends
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.users = request.users
            post.save()

            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = HomeForm()
            return redirect('home:home')

        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

def change_friends(request, operation, pk):
    friend = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if operation == 'add':
        Friend.make_friend(request.users, friend)
    elif operation == 'remove':
        Friend.lose_friend(request.users, friend)
    return redirect('home:home')
```

Comment: Try `reverse('accounts:view_profile_with_pk')`?

Comment: Share the template where the error happens.

Comment: Mr./Mrs Willem Van Onsem I have shared it now it is called profile.html

Comment: Mr./Mrs  D Malan where do i try reverse('accounts:view_profile_with_pk') in the views.py?

Comment: Can you share the base template as well?

Comment: Of course i did

Comment: Can you also add the `models.py` file?

Comment: In your `home.html` you are using the `view_profile_with_pk` route twice. Once for each user and once for each friend. Can you comment those out, one at a time, and see if you still get the error?

Comment: it didnt work out

Comment: neither one worked? The user one and the friend one both had errors?

Comment: Change your `urls.py` entry to `path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.view_profile, name='view_profile_with_pk'),`

Comment: now i am getting NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'view_profile_with_pk' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account\\/profile\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: i am getting AttributeError at /
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'users'

Comment: Can you add your `views.py` that contains your home route?

Comment: I added it now. thank you for staying with me until now btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now that you are passing a pk value using `{% url 'view_profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}`

Based on the error:

```
Exception Value: Reverse for 'view_profile_with_pk' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found.
```

There is not a pk value being passed on. I see that you are using this url in two places in your `home.html` file.

This leads me to believe that either the `user` or `friend` object doesn't exist in your loop. Check the `views.py` file that has your home route. Make sure you are sending valid variables for both `users` and `friends`. Ensure you are using `users` and not `user`

#### Edit:

In the `views.py` that contains your home route, You create a variable called `friends` If the user is authenticated, `friends` contains all friends belonging to the user. If the user is not authenticated, however, you assign `friends` to a tuple `friends=(1,)`. This tuple will not have a primary key value.

When the url attempts to pass the pk value it will be empty. Try changing the value of `friends` to `None` if the user is not authenticated.

Comment: I added my home.html and as you see I am already using this method

Comment: I see that. Are you using `get_absolute_url()` in your models.py file?

Comment: I am not I added my models .py btw

Comment: should I assign it to 0?

Comment: but now I am getting an error I think it is easy for you to solve can you help me or you are bored enough?

Comment: You will need to create another question